# Do I have to mark addresses that I want to send ETH to in vyper as payable?

Tags: addresses, payable, vyper

In solidity, if I want to send ETH to an address, I have to mark it as payable.

Do I need to do this in vyper?

Solidity example:

```js
payable(msg.sender)
```

Answer (score 1):

No. All addresses are payable.